# CSS - Column aligned to bottom of page but grows with scrolling content.

Tags: css, layout

http://jsfiddle.net/yLhh3/

I have three columns in a deadly simple CSS layout. They look perfect until content is added to one of them thus forcing the page to scroll (scroll down on the fiddle).

All I want is for the red boxes to ALWAYS go to the bottom of the page (not the window / screen, the page). How can this be accomplished with CSS?

```
.column
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;

    /* Page height minus header */
    min-height: calc(100% - 192px);

    /* Align to bottom of the page */
    position: absolute;
    top: 192px; 
}

/* Half the page width minus (1.5 columns + offset between columns) */
.left { left: calc(50% - 630px); }
.right { right: calc(50% - 630px); }

/* Half the page width minus 0.5 columns */
.center { left: calc(50% - 200px); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has always been issues and questions about this and there are many ways to go about it, but the easiest, since your using absolute positioning, it to wrap the "column" divs inside the "center" div.

```
<div class="column center">
    <div class="column right"></div>
    <div class="column left"></div>
</div>
```

This allows the left and right divs to strech to 100% of the parent, the center.  Some minor changes to the css, as you can see in the fiddle, like `height: 100%` and `top: 0` for the contained columns since the parent top is considered 0 for the children.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JThomas/yLhh3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you are trying to achieve.

I've used `overflow: scroll;` so you would not lose the content (You can set it to only Y if you want or hidden).
I've also used `height` since with `min-height` the `overflow` didn't triggered

```
.column
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 400px;

    /* Page height minus header */
    height: calc(100% - 192px);

    /* Align to bottom of the page */
    position: absolute;
    top: 192px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want, I want the whole page to scroll when content in the columns is added. But I want the height of the other two columns to match that of the longest. Either that or for them to all magically find the page height and just be that.

Comment: Seems like @Justin provide you with a solution then.